# dragging user controls from one flowlayoutpanel to another

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, flowlayoutpanel

how can i add drag and drop capability of a custom usercontrol from 2 flowlayoutpanels?

Usercontrol keeps being null on the following line of code below

```
    private void flowLayoutPanel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl userControl = e.Data.GetData(typeof(UserControl)) as UserControl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with what you are doing is that to extract the data that is stored inside the drag, you have to specify the **exact** type.

```
control.DoDragDrop(new Label(), DragDropEffects.Move);

e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Control)) // = false
e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Label)) // = true
```

What you have to do is create a wrapper and use that for your drag-and-drop code.

```
class ControlWrapper
{
  public Control Control { get; private set; }
  public ControlWrapper(Control control) { Control = control; }
}

control.DoDragDrop(new ControlWrapper(new Label()), DragDropEffects.Move);

e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ControlWrapper)) // = true
```

And your code now becomes

```
ControlWrapper controlWrapper = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ControlWrapper)) as ControlWrapper;
UserControl userControl = controlWrapper.Control as UserControl;
```

And trying not to sound too preachy, but you should check if the data exists in the form you want first. `e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ControlWrapper))` will tell you if it is that format.